# Python Pandas Join, Merge and Concat

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I want to merge three data frames(A,B and C) and have to consider all column of A data frame and few columns for B data frame based on matched column and same with column c data frame.

[image]

this link having has an image.

http://prntscr.com/hvnol9

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: that document I have seen but I can't able to put my logic here, how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

As you describe it you could have done that on your own. Concat `B` and `C` then Merge it with `A`.

```
A.merge(pd.concat([B,C]), on=['ID','ID_NAME'])

   ID ID_NAME Address         DOB   SALARY   SCHOOL
0   1       A     ABC  1988-10-11      NaN      DPN
1   2       B     CDE  1988-10-12      NaN      NNN
2   3       C     FGH  1988-10-13      NaN  GURUKUL
3   4       D     FGH  1988-10-14      NaN      DPS
4   5       E     FGH  1988-10-15      NaN      NNN
5   6       F     FGH  1988-10-16  20000.0      NaN
6   7       G     FGH  1988-10-17   1000.0      NaN
7   8       H     FGH  1988-10-18   2000.0      NaN
8   9       I     FGH  1988-10-19   3000.0      NaN
9  10       J     FGH  1988-10-20   2000.0      NaN
```

Comment: It's not returning any rows here, just returning columns and index.Columns: [ID, ID_NAME, Address,DOB,SCHOOL,SALARY]
Index: []

Comment: Give the data in the form of text, there might be cleaning required. I can't copy data from a image.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fmdD3CCVLGFzmxgfvtPIjwpA0f7QroDs/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wt0Qa5AM3kWpXuUUGj93Cy1X6ZSAnieG/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eFlBpd7jBE0NhuXh9-Qtw777nsOLjWJy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's not working at my end. let me give you real data. on that data, sheet2 having data which I want from different sheets.

Comment: It's not working at my end. let me give you real data. on that data, sheet2 having data which I want from different sheets.https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VwFEod4dyyxlK52uMtCI5rZJNeI1utgI

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792086/panda-merge-return-empty-dataframe... this is happening with me, but in my case data types are int on all values. still not able to get the values.

Comment: summary_data_summary dtypes KM_data_summary dtypes daily_sales_data_summary dtypes
PLACEMENT_ID  int64 PLACEMENT_ID  int64 PLACEMENT_ID int64
PLACEMENT_DESC object PLACEMENT_DESC object PLACEMENT_DESC object
SDATE datetime64[ns] IMPRESSIONS int64 VIEWS int64
EDATE datetime64[ns] ENGAGEMENTS int64 CLICKS int64
CREATIVE_DESC object    
METRIC_DESC object    
COST_TYPE_DESC object    
UNIT_COST float64    
BUDGET float64    
BOOKED_QTY float64    
     
dtype: object  dtype: object  dtype: object

Comment: @dharmendramishra Add this info in the question. Comment section ain't pretty.