# Pandas merge returning empty frame despite same dtypes?

Tags: pandas, time-series

I am having trouble merging two dataframes in pandas. I found [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792086/pandas-merge-return-empty-dataframe), but since the dtype of 'date' are both 'object' (i.e. the same dtype?), I'm not sure what to do. I am reading day_vals using pd.read_csv.

```
df['date']=df.index.date
print(df.head())
print(df.dtypes)

day_vals=pd.read_csv(myfile,parse_dates=True)
print(day_vals.head())
print(day_vals.dtypes)

df=df.merge(day_vals,left_on='date',right_on='date')
print(df.head())
```

The results:

```
                           date            datetime  hour
datetime                                                 
2017-07-22 16:00:00  2017-07-22 2017-07-22 16:00:00    16
2017-07-22 17:00:00  2017-07-22 2017-07-22 17:00:00    17
2017-07-22 18:00:00  2017-07-22 2017-07-22 18:00:00    18
2017-07-22 19:00:00  2017-07-22 2017-07-22 19:00:00    19
2017-07-22 20:00:00  2017-07-22 2017-07-22 20:00:00    20
date                object
datetime    datetime64[ns]
hour                 int64
dtype: object
         date  daily
0  2017-07-22  0.013
1  2017-07-23  0.013
2  2017-07-24  0.013
3  2017-07-25  0.013
4  2017-07-26  0.013
date      object
daily    float64
dtype: object
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [date, datetime, hour, daily]
Index: []
```

Comment: Lets test... `df['date'].head() == day_vals.loc[0, 'date']`, should be all true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both columns being of `object` dtype doesn't guarantee that individual elements are of the same type.

To merge, you can simply assign a new dtype to columns temporarily:

```
pd.merge(df.assign(date=df.date.astype(str)), 
     day_vals.assign(date=day_vals.date.astype(str)), 
     how='left', on='date')
```

Better yet, convert them properly to datetime.

Comment: Accepted based on "convert them properly to datetime." But I'm not sure whey df.index.date doesn't return a "proper" datetime or why pd.read_csv(...,parse_dates=True) doesn't either.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution (duh):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
day_vals['date'] = pd.to_datetime(day_vals['date'])
```

But is there a better way to get the value "to_datetime" while reading the csv and/or building df? It seems like I am missing something....

```
day_vals=pd.read_csv(pETdaily,parse_dates=True)

hr_rng = pd.date_range(start=piez.start, end=piez.stop, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(hr_rng, columns=['date'])
df['date']=df.index.date
```

My dates seem pretty standard to me, so I don't see why pd.to_datetime() is required after reading.
From [pd.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html): "For non-standard datetime parsing, use pd.to_datetime after pd.read_csv."

Also not sure why df.index.date requires pd.to_datetime() after
From [pd.DateTimeIndex.date](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html): "Returns numpy array of python datetime.date objects (namely, the date part of Timestamps without timezone information)."